# AES 128 bit encryption for Informatica Powercenter

Tags: encryption, aes, informatica-powercenter

In a oracle database i have a table with a column that contains 'words' with the length of 17 ASCI characters (136 bits). I want to encrypt those words in Informatica Powercenter v10 with AES 128 bit. This is not possible because the plain text is 136 bits which is bigger then 128 bits and the last character will be ignored. Informatica dosen't have a higher bit encryption method. How should i procced in this case? Did any of you encounter this? 
I thought I break the 17 character word into smaler words and encrypt/decrypt them separately and and concatenate them after.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This is a non-issue for any modern platform.  Yes, AES has a 128-bit block size, but the implementation should automatically encrypt further blocks as neccessary.  You might be interested in *cryptographic padding* for further reading.

Comment: the version of informatica AES implementation takes just the first 16 characters and ignores the rest. it doesn't implement any further blocks. Furthermore, I cannot change the aes function within Informatica

Comment: Well that's yuck.  My next approach would be what you suggested - break in half and encrypt.

Comment: @StefanCreanga Find a full implementation of AES  that supports arbitrary data lengths. Also as Luck mentioned you swill also need padding or a mode that does not require padding.

Answer (score 1):

This seems as if you're using the "words" as encryption `key`. `AES_ENCRYPT` function takres two arguments:

- `value` - string to be encrypted. If my understanding is correct, here your "words" should go. No special length restrictions here, so any string port can be used.
- `key` - the encryption key to be used. **This** has a limit of 16 characters. This is what should be used to decrypt at some later point in time.

===================== UPDATE =====================

Knowing the details from comments below, I tried to reproduce the error. I put a very simple mapping together, that uses two ports to generate the encrypted text:

- `AES_ENCRYPT('Some 16char text', 'mykey')` - this text has exactly 16 characters, as instructed
- 1AES_ENCRYPT('Some 16char text, plus more text.', 'mykey')1 - exactly the same, 16 character text plus some additional characters.

What I'm trying to prove is that the input is truncated to 16 characters regardless of it's length and hence the output of `AES_ENCRYPT` will be same.
The mapping:

[image: AES_ENCRYPT initial mapping]

Here's the output:

[image: AES_ENCRYPT initial mapping output file]

Same shows up in my SQL Server target:

[image: AES_ENCRYPT initial mapping output DB]

Indeed: the result is EXACTLY the same, the text seems truncated. You're right!

I'd just like to note here, that it would be great if you'd have this prepared. This would save me some time.

===================== SOLUTION =====================

Now, being able to reproduce and confirm the issue, I tried to solve it.

The results are:
[image: AES_ENCRYPT modified mapping output file]

SQL Server:
[image]

You were right: the text got trucated. So I changed the length ot the ports:

[image: AES_ENCRYPT modified mapping]

Hope this helps!

Comment: the plaintext (value) also has a restriction of 128 bits

Comment: No, it does not have any limitation. Please see the two examples here: upper demonstrates the key-too-long issue, on lower screen you can see that all is fine: https://imgur.com/a/ggINzJJ

Comment: try the following scenario: encrypt two 17 characters long strings and modify just the last character of one of the strings (this is the exact case that i have in the PROD environment which afected 8 mil contracts). The result of the encryption will be the same because you have to feed the AES_ENCRYPT function blocks of 128 bits not higher. If you feed higher then 128, the AES_ENCRYPT insted of breaking the string in 128 bit blocks of data it will just cut of the characters higher then 16. Please prove this wrong

Comment: and the 'nice' part is that is dosen't return any error, it just works